# Loading a UserControl from a .NET 5 library into .NET Framework (4.8) Project

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, .net-5

I have successfully upgraded a .NET Framework (4.8) project to .NET 5 (Core).

I had previously referenced this assembly from another .NET framework project (where I shared a `UserControl`).

When calling this newly upgraded assembly (via `Assembly.LoadFrom()`) from an older .NET Framework project, I get the following error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Is it feasible to load this .NET 5 assembly from within my .NET Framework project or is simply impossible?

Comment: You can't. You can't load a .NET Core library in a .NET Framework application. NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. If you want to use the same code from both runtimes you'll have to create a .NET Standard 2.1 library. You won't be able to add any UI components to that library though, because .NET Standard doesn't contain any UI-specific APIs. It's meant to be cross-platform

Comment: In general, only a few class library types in Visual Studio can be used everywhere, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have upgraded the application to .NET 5, you should also update your class libraries to either .NET 5 or .NET Standard depending on whether you have any consuming applications left on the .NET Framework or .NET Core.

An application running on the .NET Framework cannot(or at least should not!) consume a .NET core assembly and vice versa. It's different runtimes.

Comment: `An application running on the .NET Framework cannot consume a .NET core assembly and vice versa. It's different runtimes.`
Is it that black-and-white? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard a .NET FW 4.8 assembly should be able to consume a .NET Core assembly up to V2.0?

Comment: Yes, it's black and white. .NET 5 is .NET **Core** 5. Neither .NET Standard nor .NET Framewok. You can load a .NET Standard library in both .NET Core and .NET Framework runtimes but you can't mix the runtimes. The link you posted is about .NET Standard, not Core. The classes, methods and even IL operations each one uses simply aren't there

Comment: And even if you can actually consume/reference the assembly, the app will crash when it tries to use an API that simply isn't there in the executing runtime. So don't mix runtimes.

Comment: Okay thanks v much for your inputs both. @mm8